# Users voting on their own posts

Tags: discussion

Why are users allowed to up/down vote their own questions and answers?
I feel that voting on your own post invalidates part of the process. Sure its only one vote, but it still matters.

Comment: Er...you can't?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't. Therefore, there are no problems.

Comment: Oh, I never actually tried clicking my own arrows before, I had assumed they worked

Comment: They work, but they work at giving you an error telling you that you can't actually do that. Stack Exchange's UI design philosophy is [don't leave stuff disabled](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/07/01.html) - leave it enabled, let it fail to work, then teach you why. Not a good design philosophy for _everything,_ but it works well here. I've never seen someone ask *"why isn't voting enabled on my post?? it works on every other post!"* or *"how many reps until I can vote on my own post?"* or so on.

Comment: @doppelgreener Lucky...

Comment: You *can* favorite your own post, though, and also accept your own answer, but neither of these affect rep (though they might affect badges).  Favoriting your own post doesn't seem to be controversial, but being able to accept your own answer was a long fight with site management to get working properly.

Comment: favoriting your own post has actual useful mechanical reasons to do so for various alerts and whatnot.